# How do I hide the Top Bar in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I am using a Page Viewer to display another SharePoint site Page and I do not want to display the Top Bar/Banner/Search of the source SharePoint page....In the Page Viewer I tried IsDlg=1 as part of the URL, but that did not work.

Thus, I tried some CSS in a script editor within the source page and was able to remove the Quick Launch, but not the Top Bar/Header....

How can I hide a page without any naigation, but yet be able to edit the page..

Comment: Does this help? SPO: http://blog.sharepointexperience.com/2015/09/stack-suite-bar-on-ribbon-sharepoint-online/ and SP2013 on-prem: http://blog.sharepointexperience.com/2014/08/stack-suite-bar-on-ribbon/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
     /* Hide the left Suite Bar and right ribbon areas */
    #suiteBarLeft {
    display: none;
     }
```

Comment: As far as I understood, the question is about the top bar and not the suitebar. Am I wrong?

Comment: it was the suitebar also, but i figured that out...